# How to plot two consecutive columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
p1=rnorm(4)
p2=rnorm(4)
p3=rnorm(4)
p4=rnorm(4)
p5=rnorm(4)
p6=rnorm(4)

df=data.frame(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6)
```

and I would like to plot it in a certain way so that only consecutive columns are the values of `x` and `y`. By that I mean that `p1` and `p2` are the first `y` and `x`, and the next `p3` and `p4` are the next `x` and `y`.

I was thinking to make each column a special vector, but I would to have a function so that 
that it does not matter how many colums I have just that I can plot the two columns each in a different colour.

So I am interested in a simple function that will plot the whole data frame for two colums at time.

Comment: So in this case, you want one plot with 3 series on it, or 3 diff plots?

Comment: @arvi1000
The same plot.

Answer (score 2):

First consider if your analysis will often require such things, because perhaps `p1`, `p3`, and `p5` has the same meaning for different cases. If that is true you will find many tasks easier if you define a factor variable for the cases and concatenate the columns (use [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)).

For a one off, try something like this, assuming all columns in your data frame are numeric and all to be plotted as you describe:

```
#the plot coerces the odd and even columns into single vectors
#note they must be of the same type
plot(x = unlist(df[seq(1,ncol(df),2)]),
     y = unlist(df[seq(2,ncol(df),2)]),
     col=rep(1:(ncol(df)/2),each=nrow(df)))
```

The color parameter `col` is an example of how to differentiate the column sets.

Comment: What if there are unequal columns? If I have NAs or zeros.

Comment: Zeros are no issue, they are just plotted on the axis. And NA does not imply unequal column length, quite the opposite. Points with an NA are not plotted. Though i believe warnings are raised.    So do you really have unequal lengths? Try `length(df$p1)` etc

Comment: Incorporated @arvi1000 suggestion to make it a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
# your random data ('df' is reserved, so using 'dat')
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4*6), ncol=6))

# extract every consecutive pair of cols to data.frame with a series name,
# store in list
df_list <- lapply(seq(1, ncol(dat), 2),
                  function(x) data.frame(series=x, x=dat[,x], y=dat[,x+1]))

# rbind the list together and plot
ggplot(do.call(rbind, df_list), aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(series))) +
    geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! Maybe setting the limits of `x` and `y` to c(-4,4) would make sense here. Or maybe center at 0 on both axes?

Comment: vpipkt's answer above is more compact, but you could take the `seq(1, ncol(dat), 2)` thing from this answer to avoid the need for the `is.even` function